# Wallet, deposit and withdrawal management system or APIs

Tags: website-integration, payment-processors

What are the most popular solutions to create a website where a user can register, deposit crypto (not only bitoin, but all major coins, e.g. ETH, BCH, XRP, XLM, DASH, EOS etc.), receive a mail confirmation on payment confirmed, withdraw etc.?

Do you think the best is to use your own custom solution (and install the relative full nodes of the coins you want to support and use their APIs to manage the wallets) or there are robust and well known software solutions to manage user deposit?

If so, can you list a few solutions one can use to create a website to accept crypto deposits?

Requirement would be, have an address for each customer, or in case of XRP & XLM, have a specific tag associated to the customer. Just like crypto exchanges work.

So far I found coinpayments.net, but from the first sight it doesn't seem to be what I'm looking for....

Comment: I'd imagine that an HYIP scam site doesn't really need any customer-specific infrastructure, since they are scams that won't pay out anyways.

Comment: This is a bit of an "XY-Question". Your main question seems to be about best practices for integrating cryptocurrency payments with a website. The HYIP context appears to be just an example in which you've seen a similar solution than what you're looking for. This question could therefore be improved by editing topic and body to focus on the main inquiry instead of the HYIP use-case.

Comment: @chytrik the actually pay... for a while. I was fascinated on how their infrastructure works so well and wondering if they probably implemented their own solution/wrapper or if they use something existing like the answer below suggest: bitgo or another famous service.

Comment: @Murch I edited the question, so now it's more generic and not anymore hyp oriented. I realize that if I want to code my own crypto exchange, the requirements would be very similar...

Answer (score 2):

Although certain coins have a few available API providers (such as BitGo for Bitcoin), any sane and security conscious company should elect to run their own nodes for each supported currency, manage their own keys, and have their own wrapper to handle deposits and withdrawals by interacting with the nodes.

This is especially relevant for coins like Monero and ZCash, where third party API providers may not be able to view transactions related to your business at all due to privacy protocols.

Once you have the infrastructure in place, the flow you described is essentially correct - you assign an address (or address+memo) to a user, and treat all incoming deposits to that address as coins belonging to that user.

Comment: Since you mentioned BitGo as a provider of Bitcoin wallets, I wanted to point out that we support 13 cryptocurrencies and over 100 ERC20 tokens. (Disclosure: I work at BitGo.)

Comment: yes any sane company would do so, but say I want to start playing around, create show case websites etc. then it's an overkill to build a super infrastructure and I'd rather outsource all the infrastructure and use APIs as you describe, which is what I'm looking for. In a later stage I'd say to create all nodes and learn to manage them properly. I'll check bitgo and see how it works, thanks.

Comment: Purely API recommendations are off topic here since they tend to be outdated easily, but you should be able to find a BitGo style hosted wallet, or an explorer that exposes the JSON-RPC interface for a coin (as etherscan does for ETH) for most popular coins. For privacy coins and less popular ones, you will likely have to operate a node.

Answer (score 0):

After some research I've seen that there are actually many POS or cryptocurrency payment gateways (some accept not only crypto, but also fiat payments, easy to be integrated in famous e-shops solutions).

Raghav gave a good answer suggesting to learn to set up your own nodes, but suggesting only BitGo as API provider is an incomplete answer.

I've found a good blog article listing several alternatives (bitgo is not in the list, but it's available through SpicePay as feature): [17 Best Cryptocurrency Payment Gateways In 2020](https://coinfunda.com/best-cryptocurrency-payment-gateways-bitcoin/)

Most of these gateways take a fee on every transaction, just like mastercard/visa etc. (but less, of course), so, from the article linked above, the free ones seem to be the following:

- [BTCPay Server](https://btcpayserver.org/) mainly for BTC & Lightning Network. Some altcoins supported via plugins.
- [GoUrl](https://gourl.io/): Open source. No Monthly Fee, Transaction Fee from 0% (1.5% per transaction for more supported altcoins)

It's not clear if there are many free alternatives, but if I missed a good one, feel free to comment of course.